# Using If/Else to write radius of circle in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, object, svg

I am trying to make the `radius` of my `circle` (`r`) in my `SVG` file to be a value of 3 if the `Site_Catagories` in the data is not `VCP Core` or `VCP Lab`. If the statement is true then I want the value to be 5. I thought to use an `IF/ELSE` statement to accomplish this but keep getting errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
<g id="dots">
    {data.sites.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <circle 
                key={i + i + '--'} 
                id={'dot' + (i + 1)} 
                class="cls-2" 
                cx={(180 + item.attributes.address.Longitude) * (1552 / 360)} 
                cy={(90 - item.attributes.address.Latitude) * (818/ 180)} 
                r={
                    if (item.attributes.Site_Catagories === 'VCP Core' || 'VCP Lab') { 
                        document.write(5);
                    }else { 
                        document.write(3);
                    }
                }
                alt={item.attributes.title} 
                fill='white'
            />
        )
    })}
</g>
```

Comment: I suggest you move all the calculation logic out of the JSX. Simply make variables to hold those calculations before the return statement. Then, in the JSX, use those variables. Your code will become a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't directly use `if-else/switch` statement inside `JSX`, use either `ternary operator` or call a `function` from `JSX` and use `if-else/switch` inside that.

Write it like this by using **ternary operator**:

```
<g id="dots">
    {data.sites.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <circle 
                key={i + i + '--'} 
                id={'dot' + (i + 1)} 
                class="cls-2" 
                cx={(180 + item.attributes.address.Longitude) * (1552 / 360)} 
                cy={(90 - item.attributes.address.Latitude) * (818/ 180)} 
                r={
                    item.attributes.Site_Catagories === 'VCP Core' ||
                    item.attributes.Site_Catagories === 'VCP Lab' ? 
                    "5" : "3"
                  }
                alt={item.attributes.title} 
                fill='white'
            />
        )
    })}
</g>
```

Reference: http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

Comment: Hi thanks. The dots do not appear now because the radius doesn't appear. Is document.write the way to make the r=3 or 5? Here is how it renders in the HTML: <circle id="dot1" class="cls-2" cx="442.6041367111111" cy="232.02370953333332" alt="Southlake VCP Site" fill="white" data-reactid=".0.2.0.0.0.0.$0--" data-svg-origin="442.6041259765625 232.02371215820312" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"></circle>

Comment: no that is not the correct way i think, check the updated answer it should work.

Comment: Thanks you are the best!